# unable to recover in Future - scala

Tags: scala, future

I expect that the following code will generate value 5 as I have written recover to handle the exception and return 5. But I always see the exception in IntelliJ. What is the mistake here?

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

object ConcurrencyExample extends App {

val time = System.currentTimeMillis()

val futures1: Future[Int] = Future {
    println("in Future.. sleeping")
    Thread.sleep(10)
    println("awakein future")
    throw new Exception("future failed")
    1
}

val result = futures1.map(x=>x+3)
result recover {
  case e:Exception => 5
}

result onComplete{
  case Success(v)=>println("result is "+v)
  case Failure(e) =>println("failed result:"+e)
}

Await.result(result,100 millis)

}
```

result

```
in Future.. sleeping
awakein future
Exception in thread "main" LegacyException: future failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not working because the future that would do the *recovering* is not the one you are calling `Await.result()` on.

From the [Future's scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/concurrent/Future.html#recover[U%3E:T](pf:PartialFunction[Throwable,U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[U]), we learn that `recover` *creates a new future that will handle any matching throwable that this future might contain. If there is no match, or if this future contains a valid result then the new future will contain the same.*

Thus, it is this *new* future you are now interested in.

Try this:

```
val result = futures1.map(x=>x+3)
             .recover {
                 case e:Exception => 5
             }

Await.result(result,100 millis)
```

Comment: Thanks. A doubt - map is being called on future1. My understanding is that map is called only when the future is successful. If the future is not successful, .recover will be called on futures1? I am unfamiliar with the syntax. You are calling futures1.map but not futures1.recover. Is this some sort of OrElse?

Comment: .map will return you a new future that is either failed, or that applies the passed operation if `futures1` succeeds. Scala's objects are generally immutable, and any method that looks like it is modifying something is actually returning you a new instance with the modifications you want. Hence, here, recover will work when `futures1` fails.